# Why can't I get what is located in memory cell n?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I was trying to get the object located at address 32. So, I wrote this code:

```
char *cp = (char *)32;
cout<<*cp<<endl;
```

However, the program crashes, displaying an msg box reading "test.exe has stopped working". How can I fix this?

Comment: What makes you think `32` is a valid address, your program is allowed to access??

Comment: What platform are you on?  If you're on an Amiga or some custom hardware then it's probably cool. If you're on a regular PC then not so much...

Comment: I use Windows 7 32-bits.

Comment: So ? What kind of object are you expecting. Just a reminder, you play with virtual addresses in C/C++ not the physical ones

Comment: Related: [In C/C++, how do I get the data in a virtual memory space?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12574351), especially Nicol's answer.

Comment: On Windows, any attempt to access an address in the first 64K of the address space will result in an access violation, so there is simply no way to do what you're doing without crashing the program.

Comment: So what is the first memory address I can access on a Windows 7 32bit machine?

Comment: There is no fixed "first memory address". But it shouldn't matter. You shouldn't be accessing memory that way. Access things you know about. Don't snoop around because you might step into a trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to think about why you're getting the behavior that you're seeing.

From a language perspective, the C++ standard says that if you access any memory that does not correspond to an object, the resulting program has *undefined behavior*. This means that C++ places absolutely no restrictions on what can happen. You might be able to read or write the memory, but it also might immediately crash the program. In principle, in an embedded device, it might literally set the computer on fire! Therefore, one answer to your question is "you accessed memory that didn't correspond to an object, so the result was undefined, and on your computer it happened to crash the program."

From a machine perspective, most implementations of C++ will interpret your code as "create a pointer to byte 32, then try to dereference it." On most operating systems, the OS and programs are set up to allocate memory for the program into different segments (code, text, stack, heap, etc.) and the operating system will terminate any program that tries to read memory outside of those segments. The reason usually has to do with virtual memory. When a program runs, the OS sets up a virtual address space for the program and comes up with a mapping from virtual addresses (what the program sees) to physical addresses (what's actually in RAM). Whenever you try to access memory, the OS will remap your lookup from the virtual address to some physical address. If the program tries to read or write a memory address that isn't part of the OS's mapping, the OS can't assign that read or write a physical memory location, so it terminates the program to avoid feeding in garbage values or clobbering other memory.

That said, on older operating systems or embedded devices, you absolutely can read or write arbitrary memory locations. For example, if you're programming a microcontroller, it might be the case that certain fixed memory addresses correspond to physical devices (lights, ports, etc.) Therefore, it's common to typecast the addresses of those devices to pointers and then to read or write the pointers. On older systems without virtual memory, a program that tried to read or write garbage memory could trash the memory of other processes, taking down the whole system or leading to serious security vulnerabilities.

I don't believe there's a mechanism in Windows to read physical memory, as it's a major security risk (imagine if a virus could read the process memory from your browser as you type in a password!) There are, I believe, some functions you can use to read and write process memory, though the system security manager might prevent them from working in cases that would cause a security issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574351/) question memory access in c/c++ is not the wild west, and unless you're on some custom OS/hardware that allows you to do such things (you'd know :) ), you should not attempt it.

Accessing any address you've not previously allocated can crash your program

So there's no *minimal address* that you can access if you want to get a piece of the heap you have to allocate it, for example in c++ (on [ideone](http://ideone.com/k22Og4) as well):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int *myC = new int(); // now I ask the OS to give me some heap space to store an int
    *myC = 123; // assign a value to it
    cout<< "Content "<< *myC << endl; // this will print 123
    cout<< "Adress "<< myC << endl;  // this will print the actual address that the OS gave for this variable 
    delete myC; // after you've used the memory allocated you have to release the memory
    return 0;
}
```

All in all the OS manages those allocations for us transparently and it's a lot better than remembering at each point in the program which addresses you've used, and which you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The first memory page is usually protected to catch NULL access errors.

Hopefully, you are doing this for curiosity's sake, and not in production software. You can handle access violations using structured exception handling on Windows or signals on Linux.